# Which row did the user swipe-to-delete?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

The user swipes 1 of the rows in a UITableView and hits the DELETE button.

The user clicks on DELETE and it brings up an UIActionSheet to pick 1 of 2 dangerous delete choices.

The user clicks on 1 of those buttons... and I run some code called "myCode:".

...

Once inside "myCode:", how do I detect which row the user is trying to delete?

Is there some kind of indexPathForDeletedRow method?

(Similar to the very handy indexPathForSelectedRow method.)

Comment: If the UIActionSheet is for a delete confirmation, don't. The delete confirmation is the actual red button revealed by swiping. Asking the user the same thing twice is annoying.

Comment: The actionSheet is for him to *CHOOSE* between of 2 dangerous actions to pick.  (I'll add my details to my original post.)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to create an ivar to hold the NSIndexPath associated with the cell pending deletion. Just save that away right before creating and presenting your action sheet.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I have countless such ivars.  More and more things to keep track of.